# How to make Ansible playbook run on first host in the group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

How can I run a playbook only on first host in the group?

I am expecting something like this:

```
---
- name: playbook that only run on first host in the group
  hosts: "{{ groups[group_name] | first }}"

  tasks:
   - debug:
       msg: "on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

But this doesn't work, gives error:

> 'groups' is undefined

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use:

```
hosts: group_name[0]
```

Inventory hosts values (specified in the `hosts` directive) are processed with a custom parser, which does not allow Jinja2 expressions like the regular template engine does.

Read about [Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html).